Pnl attribution to alphas
I have about 10 alphas. I assign each of these alphas a weight and then add them up to form a combined alpha. Now I am feeding this to a mean variance optimizer that considers transaction costs and various constraints and trades about 100 assets. I can then run a backtest. I would like to get some Pnl attribution to the signals. What are possible ways to do that? I could of course run some kind of rolling regression between the strategy pnl and the pnl for running the backtest using only one of the signals, but that doesn't really work well if the signal return streams are correlated. Is there anything better? I'm sure people running quantitative equity long short programs must have some way of attributing their pnl to individual alphas for example

Take a look at Performance attribution for
multifactorial equity portfolios by
Frédéric Abergel and Thomas Heckel
